How to stimulate the dull colors of projector screens on my PC screen?
This picture shows the difference in colors between OLED screen and projector screen
Everytime I design something on my device, my device's OLED screen displays colors perfectly vibrant. However, once it's time for presentation or showcase, the projector screens makes the colors really dull.
How to simulate/preflight the projector screen on my PC? There are tools to check greyscale. But I am looking for something that works similarly but for colors.
The idea is to design with end-result on projector screen in mind. This is to design better by replacing the colors that appear dull with those that work better on such screens.

Try downloading a colour profiling tool such as Adobe colour or ChromaPure?

There is no defined color space for that. Too many factors influence the final projected image. Distance, projector screen, other light, ...

The only sure method is using the projector as a secondary monitor.

A projector works best in a darkened (not lit) room with dark (not white) walls. Otherwise you end up with a washed-out image like you have photographed.

As @sawdust states, the picture clearly shows there is too much ambient light for that projector. If you cannot control ambient lighting, then there is no way to make the projected image correct -- even an attempt to compensate in some way would fail when lighting changes.

You've asked the same question in r/powerpoint on SubReddit, and there's a discussion going on there already.  And @DrMoishePippik, the problem as OP has stated it is not to make the projected image look like the computer screen; it's to see on the computer screen what the projected image will look like, as far as is possible.

@SteveRindsberg, that's trivial: aim a bright light at the computer monitor so it, too is washed out, and in the same way.

Simulate a washed-out image by adjusting video controls for a reduced contrast and color-saturation, with a small increase in brightness on your PC monitor. But this seems to be an XY problem. You really can't remedy a washed-out image by compensating with merely enhancing contrast and saturation at the source, when the actual problem is happening at the screen. The projector itself also has limits as to how much light and contrast it output. You'll also have to guess at the amount of ambient/stray light, which likely will vary.

"But I am looking for something that works similarly but for colors" - Color accuracy is measured with an instrument called a colorimeter or color calibrator.

@DrMoishePippik "that's trivial: aim a bright light at the computer monitor so it, too is washed out, and in the same way." Except not in the same way. Projected colors look washed out partially due to interference from room light, but also because projectors simply can't produce the color saturation that a monitor can.

As I explained to OP on Reddit, there actually used to be a color calibration device specifically for use with projectors; it came with a PowerPoint add-in that could use the color profile generated by the device for any specific projector/screen/distance/room light situation and adjust the colors in PowerPoint to produce a very reasonable preview of what the projected image would look like and/or adjust the color values output to the projector to produce the best possible result. Apparently, not enough people cared enough about color accuracy. Nobody bought the thing.  A pity.

@SteveRindsberg Do you happen to remember the name of the add-in? I'm looking for something exactly what you described

@RawahaKB The add-in and matching hardware product name changed several times (marketing people, I guess). But the company no longer sells either, and the add-in's no longer available. It was written long enough ago that there's little chance it'd work in current PPT versions, in any case. I have that from a pretty reliable source: I wrote the add-in. :-)
